# Dynamically creating a Texture2D

Tags: c#, image, xna, textures

I wanted to create a semi-transparent overlay for my screen and decided to dynamically create a custom `Texture2D` object using the following code:

```
const int TEX_WIDTH = 640;
const int TEX_HEIGHT = 480
Texture2D redScreen;

void GenerateTextures(GraphicsDevice device)
{
    redScreen = new Texture2D(device, TEX_WIDTH, TEX_HEIGHT);
    uint[] red = new uint[TEX_WIDTH * TEX_HEIGHT];
    for (int i = 0; i < TEX_WIDTH * TEX_HEIGHT; i++)
        red[i] = 0x1A0000ff;
    redScreen.SetData<uint>(red);
}
```

And it just doesn't seem to work as expected! Looking at this code, I would expect the alpha value to be about 10%. (0x1A / 0xFF = ~10)

but it ends up being much more than that.
It seems to me that the `uint` represents an ARGB value, but the transparency value is never what I set it to be. it's either "somewhat transparent" or not transparent at all.

I don't like asking vague questions, 
**But what am I doing wrong?

what's wrong with this code snippet?**

**Edit:**
In the end, I could only get the wanted results by setting `BlendState.NonPremultiplied` in the `spriteBatch.Begin()` call.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

XNA by default uses pre-multiplied alpha so you have to multiply all of the color values by the alpha value. Also there is a [color struct](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.xna.framework.color.color%28v=xnagamestudio.40%29.aspx) that you might find convenient. So I suggest the below. Alpha should be between 0 and 1 inclusive.

```
const int TEX_WIDTH = 640;
const int TEX_HEIGHT = 480
Texture2D redScreen;

void GenerateTextures(GraphicsDevice device)
{
    redScreen = new Texture2D(device, TEX_WIDTH, TEX_HEIGHT);
    uint[] red = new uint[TEX_WIDTH * TEX_HEIGHT];
    for (int i = 0; i < TEX_WIDTH * TEX_HEIGHT; i++)
        red[i] = new Color(255, 0, 0) * Alpha;
    redScreen.SetData<uint>(red);
}
```

Comment: Ugh, this generated unexpected results as well. In the end, setting `BlendState.NonPremultiplied` in the `spriteBatch.Begin()` call "fixed" everything.

Comment: Just do you know BlendState.NonPremultiplied is going to cause a small performance hit compared to any of the other blending modes.

Comment: That is unfortunate, but unless I can find a way to achieve this in the normal `BlendState` mode, I'm afraid I have no other choice.

Comment: I got home and tested this out quietly on my own PC, and it seems to work. (at least the concept does, I used a `Color` array) So, correct answer for joo. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

I don't see you specifying a surface/pixel format. Are you sure each pixel is a uint?

To be sure, create a texture with a specified layout and then calculate the value in it for a given R, G, B and A.

Comment: well, `SetData` is a generic function, so I figured that passing `uint` as a generic parameter will set that format to such.

Comment: @Acidic the only one that is guaranteed to work correctly is using `Color` - unless you do your own color packing that is.

Comment: @Acidic. No, the texture format is set when created and cannot be changed. Use Color.FromArgb and Color.ToArgb if the surface format is AARRGGBB. Otherwise, define a struct with the correct layout and the [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)] and operate on it.

Comment: @ananthonline The `Color` I'm referring to is from `Microsoft.Xna.Framework` and doesn't have such methods. I found a fix for the problem anyway.